# Passing data to Pthread using structure in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I want to run Pthreads in c. i am comfortable with sending integer values to Pthread in c. But when I am **passing the data structure to the thread**, it is printing garbage values.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS   3

typedef struct MyStructure
{
      int id;
      char *myName;
}myst;

void *PrintHello(void *threadArgs)
{
      myst *myPersonalSt;

      myPersonalSt = (myst *) threadArgs;

      printf("Thread %d and Name : %s \n", myPersonalSt->id ,   
      myPersonalSt->myName);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
      long taskids[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
      int rc, t;
      char myNameArray[NUMBER_OF_THREADS][100] = {"kp" , "kkp" , "ap"};

      myst **mystArray;
      mystArray = (myst **)malloc(NUMBER_OF_THREADS*sizeof(myst));

      for(t=0;t<NUMBER_OF_THREADS;t++)
      {
                mystArray[t] = (myst *)calloc(1,sizeof(myst));
                mystArray[t]->id = t+1;
                mystArray[t]->myName = myNameArray[t];
      }

      for(t=0;t<NUMBER_OF_THREADS;t++) {

                printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
                rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, 
                           (void  *) mystArray);

                if (rc) {
                          printf("ERROR; return code from 
                    pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                          exit(-1);
                }
      }

      for(t=0;t<NUMBER_OF_THREADS;t++) {
                pthread_join(threads[t],NULL); 
      }

      pthread_exit(NULL); // this takes an input parameter !

     }
```

I was thinking that it was a problem with MALLOC (because it doesn't  initialize memory allocated). So I used CALLOC , but the same problem occured.

Comment: There is no need to cast to or from `void *` (except for `printf`s `%p`, which you don't use). You can remove all your casts, especially those in front of `malloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: if i remove the cast and use %p , it will give me something like this :
**
Creating thread 0 
Creating thread 1 
Thread 0x8582028 and Name : 0x8582038  
Creating thread 2
Thread 0x8582028 and Name : 0x8582038 
Thread 0x8582028 and Name : 0x8582038  **

Comment: You don't need to use `%p`, I was being somewhat pedantic. But now you can see that you're passing the same pointer to every thread. Hint: you're passing a pointer to your `mystArray`, you probably meant `mystArray[t]`.

Comment: @KrunalParmar - It would be nice if you can reduce your code and put only the relevant portion of the code that can reproduce the problem, from now on

Comment: @amrith-krishna Sir , this was only for my practice and for being used to threading in c. So i posted the code. but from now , i will take care of this. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, 
                       (void  *) mystArray);
```

You're missing the array index here, you mean `mystArray + t`.

On a side note: remove all these casts, they make the code hard to read. `void *` is generic and implicitly convertible in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, 
                       (void  *) mystArray);
```

Given how you're written the rest of the code, it should be:

```
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, 
                       (void  *) ( mystArray[t] ) );
```

But the use of `malloc()/calloc()` is unnecessary:

```
       myst mystArray[ NUMBER_OF_THREADS ];
       memset( mystArray, 0, sizeof( mystArray ) );
       ...
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, 
                       (void  *) &( mystArray[t] ) );
```

That will work without the `malloc()/calloc()`.